# Is Phonegap capable of downloading new HTML/Javascript at runtime?

Tags: mobile, cordova, hybrid

Does Phonegap offer the facility for an app to change all or part of its UI or business logic in the field, by downloading fresh HTML/CSS/Javascript at runtime?

Are there any examples of hybrid apps which do this?

Answer (score 1):

It can.  Just look into HTML5 AppCache manifest configuration on the server.  One quirk is that Apple will reject your App for doing this.

Comment: This isn't quite what I was looking for -- I was talking about apps which ship with HTML/CSS/Javascript built-in to them (i.e. not originally retrieved from a server), but then update parts of it afterwards.

Comment: What you're asking for is very specific implementation.  PhoneGap just focus on the basic.  It's up to you on how to implement what you need.  For example, you could use the FILE API to store file you retrieve with ajax or with file api File Transfer.  Otherwise, there are third party (non-free) built based on PhoneGap out there such as Icenium.